# In a docker Cardano node where are address key files created?

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, cardano-cli

I'm running a dockerized Cardano node and I'm trying to generate keys for a new address with the cardano-cli using the command:

```
cardano-cli address key-gen --verification-key-file 01.vkey --signing-key-file 01.skey
```

Docker command to run the node:

```
docker run -e NETWORK=mainnet -v cardano-node-ipc:/ipc -v cardano-node-data:/data inputoutput/cardano-node
```

Docker command to run the cardano-cli call:

```
docker run -it --entrypoint cardano-cli -e NETWORK=testnet -e CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH=/ipc/node.socket -v cardano-node-ipc:/ipc inputoutput/cardano-node
```

Where are those files created?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling the cardano-cli with docker run, I just got into the pod running the node in a bash shell and ran the cardano-cli from there, the files are created in the folder the bash shell runs the command.